# Irrationally termed converging infinite series

Tags: power-series

Some power series consist of an infinite number of rational terms converging to an irrational limit.

Is there a series expansion /expression built on terms of powers of $\pi$ or $e$  summing up to 1 ?

If not, any proof that a such cannot exist?

Comment: Well, one boring example is $1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\pi - 1}{\pi^n}$, but that equality works for any number bigger than 1.